# In my javascript function I am trying to get the values from a form user input to a function I created and the output the answer

Tags: javascript, function, input

I am trying to get the values from my form into a function and return a value
Here is my function

```
function createInput(){
  var weight;
  weight = document.bmiCalc.weight.value;

  var height = getElementById('height').value;
  input.onclick = function calcBMI()
    {
    // calculate users BMI

    var BMI = weight * 703 / Math.pow(height, 2);
  return BMI;
  }
  document.getElementById("BMI").appendChild();
}
```

and here is my form code from my html page

```
    <form id="bmiCalc">
      <h2> Calculate your Current BMI</h2>
        <p><label> Please enter your weight in lbs: <input type="text" name = "weight" id=   "weight"></label></p>
        <p><label>  Please enter your height in inches: <input type="text" name ="height" id="height"></label>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
        <p><label> Your current BMI is: <input name="BMI" id="BMI"></label></p>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed your html and js:

http://jsfiddle.net/CQxnx/

html:

```
<h2> Calculate your Current BMI</h2>
<label> Please enter your weight in lbs:</label> <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight">
<br />    
<label>  Please enter your height in inches:</label> <input type="text" name="height" id="height">
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="calcBMI();" />
    <br />

 <div id="msg"></div>
```

js:

```
function calcBMI(){
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;

    var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
     // calculate users BMI

    var BMI = weight * 703 / Math.pow(height, 2);
    var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
    msg.innerHTML = 'Your current BMI is:' + BMI;

}
```

Comment: You have a jsfiddle like which is working ! [http://jsfiddle.net/CQxnx/](http://jsfiddle.net/CQxnx/)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a bit off, but you never actually call the `createInput` function.  Even after that, you don't actually append the input button.  There is no `BMI` ID element, and `createInput` would calculate the weight/height as they are when it's called, not when the button is clicked.

Instead, you should just put the button in the DOM to begin with and bind the calculation function to it.

```
document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById("BMI").textContent =
        document.getElementById('weight').value * 703 /
        Math.pow(document.getElementById('height').value, 2);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fsKNb/